# compare with angular object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Following my angular object

```
  $scope.obj1= [
    {"NewID":38,"Type":"Faculty","Year":"2016","Status":"Active"},
    {"NewID":39,"Type":"Staff","Year":"2016","Status":"Active"},
    {"NewID":40,"Type":"Faculty","Year":"2016","Status":"Active"},
    {"NewID":41,"Type":"Faculty","Year":"2016","Status":"Active"}
 ]
```

I want to check 'Type' contains any 'Staff' or 'Faculty' for that I use following code

```
      var myobj=$scope.obj1;

       var x=false; y=false;

          for (var i = 0; i < myobj.length; i++) {
            if ( myobj[i].Type == 'Faculty') {                    
                x=true;
                break;
            }

          }
         for (var i = 0; i < myobj.length; i++) {

            if ( myobj[i].Type == 'Staff') {
                y=true;  
               break;               
            }
          }
```

i used JavaScript for that i am looking for easy way in angular or JavaScript rather than using for loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var filteredObjects = $scope.obj1.filter(function(obj){
   return obj.Type === 'Faculty' || obj.Type === 'Staff';
})
```

This will return you an array with the filtered objects (Type 'Faculty' and 'Staff'). You can check the `length` to see if there's any or do any other operations you need.

**EDIT**
Since you only want to check if it contains any 'Faculty' or 'Staff' you should use [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead.

```
var exists = $scope.obj1.some(function (obj) { 
    return obj.Type === 'Faculty' || obj.Type === 'Staff';
}
```

For separate result you could just create the `function`

```
function checkExists (type) {
    return $scope.obj1.some(function (obj) { 
        return obj.Type === type;
    }
}
var facultyExist = checkExists('Faculty');
var staffExist = checkExists('Staff');
```

Comment: Rather than filtering and checking the length, you could also use [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), which returns a boolean based on whether any of the elements match the predicate.

Comment: I don't think you misread the question at all. This is still a good answer

Comment: i want separate result for  'faculty' and 'staff' for that  Should i write separate code  or any common way

Comment: I've edited for you @Pravin. That provides you separate result for both types

Answer (score 3):

filter will create a new array every time, try this if all you need is to know if the object exists:

```
obj1= [
    {"NewID":38,"Type":"Faculty","Year":"2016","Status":"Active"},
    {"NewID":39,"Type":"Staff","Year":"2016","Status":"Active"},
    {"NewID":40,"Type":"Faculty","Year":"2016","Status":"Active"},
    {"NewID":41,"Type":"Faculty","Year":"2016","Status":"Active"}
 ];

 const includes = -1 !== obj1.findIndex(item => item.Type === "Faculty" || item.Type === "Staff" );

// in case your browser doesnt support arrow functions:
 const includes2 = 
    -1 !== obj1.findIndex(
    function (item) {
      return  item.Type === "Faculty" || item.Type === "Staff";
      }
    );
```

Comment: Added code in case your browser doesnt support arrow functions or if you dont use Babel

Answer (score 0):

```
  obj1.forEach(function(val,index){
  if(val.type=='Faculty)
  {
   //your code
   } 
  else if(val.type == 'Staff')
  {
     //your code
 })
```